# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy import special
import math
class geotherm:
##    Relationship between temperature and depth
    def __init__(self,t0=10.0,q0=0.0565,qm=0.03,h=10000.0,a=0.000001,dt=1300.0,z=0.0,k=3.35,t=0.0):
##    This initiates class geotherm
        self.t0=t0
        self.q0=q0
        self.qm=qm
        self.h=h
        self.a=a
        self.dt=dt
        self.z=z
        self.k=k
        self.t=t

    def continent(self,x):

        **tc=self.t0+((self.qm**self.z)/self.k)+((((self.q0-self.qm)*self.h)/self.k)*[1.0-math.exp(self.z/self.h)])**
        return(tc)

    def oceanic(self,y):

        to=self.t0+((self.dt*special.erf)*(self.z/(2.0*np.sqrt(self.a*self.t))))
        return(to)


x=np.linspace(0.0,30000.0)
y=np.linspace(0.0,30000.0)
crust1=geotherm(t0=10.0,q0=0.0565,qm=0.03,h=10000.0,z=30000.0,k=3.35)
crust2=geotherm(t0=10.0,dt=1300.0,z=30000.0,t=((30.0*(10.0**6.0))*(math.pi*(10.0**7.0))))
crust3=geotherm(t0=10.0,dt=1300.0,z=30000.0,t=((60.0*(10.0**6.0))*(math.pi*(10.0**7.0))))
temp1=crust1.continent(x) ##############
temp2=crust2.oceanic(y)
temp3=crust3.oceanic(y)
plt.plot(x,temp1,'-r')
plt.plot(y,temp2,'-b')
plt.plot(y,temp3,'-g')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')
plt.ylabel('Depth (m)')
plt.legend(['Crust 1','Crust 2','Crust 3'])
plt.show()
```

In line marked with ######  or ** is where i get an error

Comment: This seems to be a pure Python rather than spatial Python library question and so I think it would be better researched/asked at [so].

Answer (score 2):

At first sight I presume your problem is the square brackets at `[1.0-math.exp...`. `[]` stand for a sequence data type (list), as your error message indicates. Replacing it with round brackets should solve your issue.

Multiplication is only defined for `integer` and `list` by means of (for example) `3 * [1,2,3]` results in `[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`. This makes no sense for `float` and `list`.